# composer cannot download mail_mime package

Tags: php, gmail, composer-php

I am trying to download mail_mime through  `composer` but I got this error as illustrated below.

```
On window command line

 C:\xampp\htdocs\google>composer install
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- The requested package pear/mail_mime dev-master exists as pear/mail_mime[1
 .10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.8.9, 1.9.0] but these are rejected by your 
  constraint.
```

Below is a capture of my composer.json file.
[image]

**So what is wrong ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `composer.json` try changining

`"pear/mail_mime":"dev-master"`

to a stable release for instance 1.10.2 as shown below.

```
"pear/mail_mime" : "1.10.2"
```

You should use a specific ( tagged stable at best ) version wherever possible.

Here's [more information](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) on how versioning and constraint works in composer.

Comment: Ok thanks JAY BHATT .But I want to know why the old parameter did not work?

Comment: @GNETODOMINIQUE https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability